# How to run Supabase and t-rex with TLS reverse proxies

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have a VPS with 2 services at different ports and self signed SSL for an IP. It is Supabase at port `8000` and t-rex service at port `6767`. I need them both on HTTPs like `https://192.0.2.1:8000` for Supabase & `https://192.0.2.1:6767` for t-rex.

I works with HTTP but how to do this with HTTP**S**? I tried it with Apache2, and it works. But I have no idea how to add `6767`? As I understand HTTPS is on port `443`.

```
<VirtualHost 192.0.2.1:443>
    ServerName 192.0.2.1:8000

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/private.key

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.0.2.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.0.2.1:8000/
</VirtualHost>

SSLEngine                on
SSLCertificateFile       /etc/ssl/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile    /etc/ssl/private/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/ssl/ca_bundle.crt
```

If this is not possible with Apache2, NGINX is fine, too.

Comment: https defaults to 443, but what makes the "s" happen is SSL and that can live on any port. So instead of having your virtual host listen on 443, have it listen on 8000 and you should be fine.

Comment: @tsc_chazz thanks, but how to make two https with ports? I need it like 
https://172.245.6.*:8000/ and https://172.245.6.*:6767/ to work on same server. Now it works only for this url https://172.245.6.*/   and when I try to use it with any port I get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: home and enduser question are offtopic. Apache has a nice manual so please [RTM](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/) on nginx you can use multiple ports in one server alias, but no apache as iirc you need to have multiple vhosts

Comment: @SERG I'll just say this: `<Virtual Host 172.246.6.*:8000>`, `<VirtualHost 172.246.6.*:6767>`, and no server name for either of them, just the raw IP address - with no port - since that's what you're using now.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ProxyPass` directives for the Supabase back-end service on port `8000` suggest the services are already listening on these ports on the same IP address; I assume it is the same with the t-rex server on port `6767`. Obviously, two services cannot listen on the same port.

```
ProxyPass / http://192.0.2.1:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.0.2.1:8000/
```

You could bind the non-TLS services to the *local loopback* and then add a *reverse proxy* to offer the TLS on the public IP address.

- For [Running Supabase Locally](https://supabase.com/blog/supabase-cli#running-supabase-locally): `const SUPABASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'`
- For [t-rex](https://t-rex.tileserver.ch/doc/serve/): `t_rex serve --bind 127.0.0.1 --port 6767`

Now you can use [Apache as a reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) with:

```
Listen 192.0.2.1:8000
Listen 192.0.2.1:6767

<VirtualHost 192.0.2.1:8000>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/private.key

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.0.2.1:6767>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/private.key

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:6767/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:6767/
</VirtualHost>
```

You do not need the [`SSLProxyEngine On`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyengine) because the back-ends are not using TLS.